# Sorting an array of Dictionaries in swift and getting operator can't be applied to Any

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I am trying to sort an `array` of `Dictionaries` by their `timeStamp` value from newest to oldest

**error: Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Any?' operands**

`timeStamp` value is saved as an `Int` into the `Dictionary`:

```
timeStamp = inviteDict["timeStamp"] as? Int
```

Dictionary:

```
[
"type": "invite",
"complimentId": key,
"status": status,
"timeStamp": timeStamp!,
 "fromUser": user
]
```

Function - combines two `arrays` of tuples, I need to sort the `array` by `timeStamp` before passing via `handler`:

```
    func getInvitesAndCompliments(forUserId forId: String, handler: @escaping ([[String : Any]], Bool) -> ()){

            var invitesAndCompliments = [[String : Any]]()

            var invites = [[String : Any]]()

            var compliments = [[String : Any]]()

            getComplimentsReceived(forUserId: forId) { (complimentsDict, success) in
                invitesAndCompliments.removeAll()
                compliments = complimentsDict
                invitesAndCompliments = invites + compliments
                handler(invitesAndCompliments, true)
            }

            getInvitesReceived(forUserId: forId) { (invitesDict, success) in
                invitesAndCompliments.removeAll()
                invites = invitesDict
                invitesAndCompliments = compliments + invites

                //sort array by timeStamp value
                let sorted_invitesAndCompliments = invitesAndCompliments.sorted(by: { $0["timeStamp"] < $1["timeStamp"] })

                handler(sorted_invitesAndCompliments, true)
            }


        }//end func
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of getting a value from a dictionary is always `Any?`, you have to downcast the types

```
let sorted_invitesAndCompliments = invitesAndCompliments.sorted(by: { ($0["timeStamp"] as! Int) < $1["timeStamp"] as! Int })
```

To avoid that use a custom struct.

Comment: Please see my edited answer (the parentheses around the `$0` expression)

Comment: PS: If you want to sort *from newest to oldest* (descending) you have to compare `>` and a dictionary is not a tuple 

Comment: Thanks so much this now addresses my original requirement. I am new to Swift/Programming in general and so I can get my head around your suggestion of using a `struct` in this case - what you're saying is that rather than saving an array of Dictionares (key : value pairs eg; "timeStamp" : "12345678"], I should write a `struct` say called `Ping` which holds each property and then hold an array of `Pings` which I can then sort on the property `timeStamp`?

Comment: Exactly, the properties have distinct types and you get rid of all that type casting.

Comment: aha! thanks so much for your advise - thanks for the tip on Dictionaries not being tuples - hehe :)

Answer (score 3):

Update your code as follows:

```
let sorted_invitesAndCompliments = invitesAndCompliments.sorted { ($0["timeStamp"] as! Int) < ($1["timeStamp"]  as! Int)}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: I tried force casting it to Int as you suggested but now I am getting `Error: Expected Type` at `$1` - what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest don't use force cast it may be crash if value is empty. Check below code:

```
let sorted_invitesAndCompliments = invitesAndCompliments.sorted(by: {
    guard let timestamp1 = $0["timeStamp"] as? Int else {return false}
    guard let timestamp2 = $1["timeStamp"] as? Int else {return false}
    return timestamp1 < timestamp2
})
```

As vadian suggested use custom struct in this case.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion and I will now look at modifying my code to include a struct as suggested, im new to swift/coding, this means more research and reading for me :)